# Deserialize the content of one of the template to check if it is in valid XML format

Tags: c#, deserialization

i want to Deserialize the  content of one of the template  to check if it is in valid XML format.Can any one give me the sample code for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for validate[sample](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_data/xml/article.php/c6737/Validation-of-XML-with-XSD.htm):

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Text;

public class XMLValidator
{
    // Validation Error Count
    static int ErrorsCount = 0;

     // Validation Error Message
    static string ErrorMessage = "";

    public static void ValidationHandler(object sender,
                                         ValidationEventArgs args)
    {
        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + args.Message + "\r\n";
        ErrorsCount ++;
    }

    public void Validate(string strXMLDoc)
    {
        try
        {
            // Declare local objects
            XmlTextReader         tr   = null;
            XmlSchemaCollection   xsc  = null;
            XmlValidatingReader   vr   = null;

            // Text reader object
            tr  = new XmlTextReader(urlpath);
            xsc = new XmlSchemaCollection();
            xsc.Add(null, tr);

            // XML validator object

            vr = new XmlValidatingReader( strXMLDoc,
                         XmlNodeType.Document, null);

            vr.Schemas.Add(xsc);

            // Add validation event handler

            vr.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            vr.ValidationEventHandler +=
                     new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationHandler);

            // Validate XML data

            while(vr.Read());

            vr.Close();

            // Raise exception, if XML validation fails
            if (ErrorsCount > 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(ErrorMessage);
            }

            // XML Validation succeeded
            Console.WriteLine("XML validation succeeded.\r\n");
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            // XML Validation failed
            Console.WriteLine("XML validation failed." + "\r\n" +
            "Error Message: " + error.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

and this code for Deserialize:

```
var reader = new StringReader(xmlString);
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(radio));
        var instance = (radio)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return instance;
```